# using winpcap without installation

Tags: c++, winpcap

I wanna use winpcap library in my project, but it would get error in other computers which winpcap is not installed. I wanna use my program in WinXP, Win7.

I checked this url: http://paperlined.org/apps/wireshark/winpcap_silent_install.html, but I can't find some files and regfiles,

Please share full files and documentation to implement.

Thanks

PS. I programmed it in Visual Studio 2008, and OS: Win7 0x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I compiled WinPcap from source and tried to use it without installation. It turned out that the driver must be installed. In addition to this, the executables which want to use WinPcap have to be able to access Packet.dll and wpcap.dll.

Comment: I found 2 files (wpcap.dll, packet.dll) in system32 folder, and I also find npf.sys file, But i don't know how to use this.

Comment: Yes, the easy part is to copy these two dlls into the directory of the exe. But the npf.sys (the driver) must be installed, I used OSR Driver Loader. First I tried to install it from the command line, but it didn't work.

Comment: The driver installer can be downloaded from http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=157 It worked for me on Windows 7 (32-bit).

Comment: If you solve this problem let me know your method with source or other. Thanks

Comment: OK. In the meantime, here is a tutorial on Windows driver creation and manual installation: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/introduction-device-drivers

Comment: I tried it, winpcap.exe/S  can install in silent mode. thanks